# Removing comments and text nodes from jQuery collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, comments, textnode

```
$html = $("<!-- comment --> <p>text</p>");
```

creates a jQuery collection like so

```
$( [the comment], [text node], p )
```

How can I access the paragraph only? .find("p") returns an empty collection

And, for extra points,

```
$html = $("<p>text</p>");
```

creates a jQuery collection like so

```
$( p )
```

Is there a fail safe way to get at the p, and only the p, that works whether the comment is there or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way is with `filter` and the universal selector `*`, which matches all *elements*.

```
$html = $("<!-- comment --> <p>text</p>").filter('*');
```

Comment: Yup. `filter` works on the collection, whereas `find` does need a "root" DOM node to start at.

Comment: To get only the `p` content,  `$('<!-- comment --> <p>text</p>').filter('p');`

Comment: @Jean-Charles Well, yes. I was going by the title of the question, using its body as an example.

Answer (score 1):

```
var p = $html.filter(function() { return this.nodeType === 1; });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zBwbC/).

Comment: That returns an empty selection. The `contents()` call isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mRgBp/). Maybe this is not exactly how you're gonna use it, but you get the point.

```
<div class="text">
    <!-- comment -->
    <p>text</p>
</div>

var html = $('.text').html();
html = $.trim(html.replace(/<!--(.*?)-->/ig, ''));
alert(html);
```

Comment: Whilst strictly speaking it solves the problem, I think that this misses the point a little.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to get by index like in `$html = $("<!-- comment --> <p>text</p>");` you can get p tag using `$($html[2])`.

OR

```
$html = $("<!-- comment --> <p>text</p>");
$target = new Object();
for(key in $html){
    if(typeof $html[key] ===  'object' && $html[key].localName === 'p')
        $target = $html[key];
}
```

Comment: better to use 'nodeName' instead of 'localName'.